# Subtract or add row value on condition MySQL

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT vcl.id
     , IFNULL(vcl.batch_id,UUID()) batchID
     , vcl.type
     , SUM(vcl.amount) amount
     , vcl.running_balance
     , vcl.date
  FROM vrcorporateledger vcl
  LEFT 
  JOIN payroll_list pl 
    ON pl.id = vcl.batch_id
 GROUP 
    BY batchID
 ORDER 
    BY vcl.created_at ASC;
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Whenever there is "CREDIT" in col type I want to increase the running balance by the value in col amount; whenever there is "DEBIT" in col type I want to decrease the accumulated balance by the value in col amount. So expected result is:

1000-2+5-4-49=950.

If possible I want to also create a column "balance" where at each point/step I see the resulting balance.

expected output like:

[image]

Comment: See CASE...WHEN

Comment: Tag only the actual database you are really using, dont spam tags, they are there to attract the correct audience to your question, dont abuse them

Comment: And don't post pictures of text. Instead, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your query should return an error because the `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns.

Comment: Keeping running balances is always FRAUGHT WITH DANGER, they are almost always wrong, but it only takes one to be wrong to destroy trust in them so making them useless

Comment: Your query is malformed. MySQL 5.7 used to allow those bad queries, but they are obsolete now. The reason is they return unpredictable results. Please fix the query and aggregate all columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause. Voting to close as is.

Comment: Avoid storing data that can be calculated. It only introduces maintenance complexity, where a change in one amount would require you to change *n* running balances.